# How to remove setter for a field with Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

There is a class

```
@Entity
// @Data or @Getter/@Setter
public class Invenetory {
   @Id
   private UUID id;
   private Sring name;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
   private StatusType status; //remove setter for this field
```

How to remove setter for that specific field with Lombok configurations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set `@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)` for the field:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Invenetory {
   @Id
   private UUID id;
   private String name;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
   @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
   private StatusType status;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
private StatusType status;
```